# Hibernate @OneToMany @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

everyone i have a question with using annotation `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne`; is it possible to create one user model with two sets of subjects in this model (conducted for the teacher and attending the student) instead of creating separate student and teacher models? I wrote such a code but when I want to get data about item and user, hibernate crashes the "Stack overflow" error.I will add that I use H2 Database.

User Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "student",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
private Set<Item> carriedItems= new HashSet<>();
}
//id and other data
```

Item entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    private User student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable = false)
    private User teacher;
}
//id and other data
```

Thanks for help @Leviand

Comment: Why are you creating a generic `Item` class instead of `Student` and `Teacher` classes?

Comment: I wonder if this is a better solution for my project becouse User has role ("teacher" or "student") and if i created Teacher and Student entity roles will not need it

Comment: second question: how is that possible that a single user is connected to multiple teachers / studends ? Is that correct?

Comment: hmm, then it better was to connect with it using FK?

Comment: Besides if i create Student and Teacher then i must create different repositories, services etc. Next problem will be loggin, how recognise who is logged if i dont have roles. I using spring rest

Comment: You can check if a `User` object is connected to student or a teacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, looks like your code and logic needs some rework.
First, use instead of `Item` pojo two dedicated classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Studend) // I'm guessing a table name
public class Student{
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = Teacher) // I'm guessing a table name
public class Teacher{
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

Then since an `User` can only be connected to a single `Teacher` or `Student`, refact that in something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = User) // I'm guessing a table name
public class User{
    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "student",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Student student;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Teacher teacher;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Its help a bit but i consider nad that model database: https://imgur.com/a/nk9uWhh

Comment: if your database looks like in that image, the code I've posted is correct :)